# Django stripe.error: Invalid card object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am trying to take a Stripe payment but I get an InvalidRequestError everytime I try to make a payment.

The payment is for a set amount of 5 Euros. I am using the credit card number 4242 4242 4242 4242 to test the payment.

My form is valid, but when it sends the payment request to Stripe I get the errors and it looks like stripe_id is blank. Any ideas?

checkout.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap_tags %}

{% block head_js %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="">
    //<![CDATA[
    Stripe.publishableKey = '{{ publishable }}';
   // ]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/stripe.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<form action="{% url 'checkout' %}" method="post" id="payment-form" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <legend>Payment Details</legend>

    <div id="credit-card-errors" style="display: none;">
        <div class="alert-message block-message error" id="stripe-error-message"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        {{ payment_form|as_bootstrap }}
    </div>

    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <input class=" btn btn-primary" id="submit_payment_btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit Payment of 5 Euros">
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class MakePaymentForm(forms.Form):
    print("MakePaymentForm...")
    MONTH_CHOICES = [(i, i) for i in range(1, 12)]
    YEAR_CHOICES = [(i, i) for i in range(2019, 2040)]
    
    credit_card_number = forms.CharField(label='Credit Card Number', required=False)
    cvv = forms.CharField(label ='Security Code (CVV)', required=False)
    expiry_month = forms.ChoiceField(label="Month",choices=MONTH_CHOICES, required=False)
    expiry_year = forms.ChoiceField(label='year',choices=YEAR_CHOICES, required=False)
    stripe_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput,  required=False)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect, reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import MakePaymentForm
from tickets.forms import TicketsForm
from tickets.models import Ticket
from django.conf import settings
from accounts.views import login, index 
from django.utils import timezone
import stripe
# Create your views here.

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET

@login_required()
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        payment_form = MakePaymentForm(request.POST)
        print("checkout...")

        if  payment_form.is_valid():
            print("Payment form is valid...")
            try:
                print("Just about to charge the customer...")
                customer = stripe.Charge.create(
                    amount=500,
                    currency="EUR",
                    description="Thank you for your contribution, it will really help our site" and request.user.email,
                    card=payment_form.cleaned_data['stripe_id']
                )
            except stripe.error.CardError:
                messages.error(request, "Your card was declined!")
            
            if customer.paid:
                print("Customer has paid...")
                messages.error(request, "You have successfully paid")
                return redirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Unable to take payment")
                return redirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            print("There are errors...")
            print(payment_form.errors)
            messages.error(request, "We were unable to take a payment with that card!")
    else:
        print("Method isn't post...")
        payment_form = MakePaymentForm()

    return render(request, "checkout.html", {"payment_form": payment_form, "publishable": settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE})
```

Here is the output in the terminal:

```
[14/Dec/2020 22:47:40] "GET /checkout/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5688
checkout...
There are errors...
<ul class="errorlist"><li>stripe_id<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
[14/Dec/2020 22:47:51] "POST /checkout/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5850
```

and here is stipe.js:

```
$(function(){
    $("#payment-form").submit(function() {
        console.log("#payment-form");
        var form = this;
        var card = {
            number: $("#id_credit_card_number").val(),
            expMonth: $("#id_expiry_month").val(),
            expYear: $("#id_expiry_year").val(),
            cvc: $("#id_cvv").val()
        };
    
    Stripe.createToken(card, function(status, response) {
        console.log("#createToken");
        if (status === 200) {
            $("#credit-card-errors").hide();
            $("#id_stripe_id").val(response.id);

            // Prevent the credit card details from being submitted
            // to our server
            $("#id_credit_card_number").removeAttr('name');
            $("#id_cvv").removeAttr('name');
            $("#id_expiry_month").removeAttr('name');
            $("#id_expiry_year").removeAttr('name');

            form.submit();
        } else {
            $("#stripe-error-message").text(response.error.message);
            $("#credit-card-errors").show();
            $("#validate_card_btn").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

And here are the errors after I submit the payment:

[InvalidRequestError 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1g4T.png)

[InvalidRequestError 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa4s1.png)

[The Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T1xP.png)

Comment: Are you sure that `createToken` is successful? ie, do you know that the `stripe_id` token id is being set before submitting to your back-end? ie, is the problem with `createToken` or is it a problem with your form data posting?

Comment: How would I know if it is successful or not?

Comment: By debugging the requests in your javascript. Probably with logging and network request inspection.

Comment: OK, I will have a go.

Comment: I have added a console.log in the javascript and there isn't any output, so I assume it isn't being called. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and the credit card payments are working fine now. I hadn't included the jQuery CDN in the header so stripe.js wasn't being called correctly!